# Securely executing user-defined code input in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I am working on a shiny app used in an econometrics course. The server loads a data set and students are expected to enter code that derives some outcome from it. The [shinyjs](https://rdrr.io/cran/shinyjs/man/runcode.html) and [shinyAce](https://github.com/trestletech/shinyAce) packages provide such functionalities. The issue with these implementations is the security risk. Students could access the file system etc. Is there a way to avoid that? A solution that restricts access to the currently loaded data set?

Consider the following minimal working example (slightly modified example from the shinyAce package):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyAce)

init <- "lm(mpg ~ drat + vs, data = example_data)"

ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
        column(
            6,
            h2("Source Code"),
            aceEditor("code", mode = "r", height = "200px", value = init),
            actionButton("eval", "Evaluate")
        ),
        column(
            6,
            h2("Output"),
            verbatimTextOutput("output")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    example_data <- mtcars
    output$output <- renderPrint({
        input$eval
        eval(parse(text = isolate(input$code)))
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: There’s *fundamentally no way* of making such code safe, short of running it in a sandbox or on the client side (which is what online IDEs do). Your `isolate` function is trivially breakable, regardless of its implementation.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks for the comment. I thought of running it in a Docker container. Do you have some good sandbox/ client side solutions in mind, which I could check?

Comment: I’m not aware of any that are ready-made. I’d start by running inside a container but I’m no expert and I’m vaguely aware that experts caution of using Docker on its own as a security sandbox, since it wasn’t designed for this purpose (for one thing, an attacker could at the very least still break a running instance, as well as exfiltrate potentially sensitive deployment secrets). All I know that getting this right is far from trivial, and it’s very easy to get it wrong.